# Calculate the sum of 2 answers

Tags: python

This is the code for a calculator function. It takes the first and second number, combines them and asks for an input whether the calculation was correct. If the input is "Yes", a statement is printed. If the input is "No", a different statement is printed.

```
def calculator(number1,number2):
    answer = ['Yes', 'yes']
    print("The first number is %d." % number1,
          "The second number is %d." % number2)
    print("The sum is %d." % (number1 + number2))
    if input("Am I right? \nANSWER : ") in answer:
        print("Knew it!")
    else:
        print("Oh, well. Blame my programmer!")
```

Is there anything I can do to optimize the code and make it shorter and / or simpler?

Comment: 'If the input is "No", a different statement is printed.' I don't see any mentioning of 'No' in your code. What will happen if I write something except Yes or No?

Comment: Yeah, I've made a mistake. I didn't account for that and simply put wired a response to "Yes" and wired another to everything else. Apologies for that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this program can be reduced a lot in *pythonic* way in terms of number for lines for sure!!

```
def calculator(number1,number2):
    try:
        print("The first number is {}\nThe second number is {}".format(number1, number2))
        print("The sum is {}".format(number1 + number2))
        print("Knew it!" if str(input("Am I right? \nANSWER : ")).lower() == "yes" else "Oh, well. Blame my programmer!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

You have not taken care of handling input *types*, what if 2 different data types are passed?

Comment: I'm hesitant to dislike this answer, but I disagree 'golfing' is the best solution here. Further, `input` is always a `str` object so there's no reason to cast it and catching exceptions here is useless.

Comment: @Coal_ :  `so there's no reason to cast it` -  what if user just hits enter without any value? || `catching exceptions here is useless` - `calculator(10, None)` would work or you should handle it for `sum` in 2nd `print` condition ? :)

Comment: My bad about the exceptions, but I'd only wrap `print("The sum is ...")` in the statement, and catch `TypeError` instead of `Exception`. Pressing return on `input` just yields an empty string. <edit> You should be printing `str(e)`, not `e`. </edit>

Comment: +1 to comment but wrapping `print("The sum is ...") ` with `try-except` is only good under assumption if input is passed in ASCII. I am assuming you are under assumption that user would always give good input....for non ascii, since encoding is not used, it would break in prints.....just think from bad input perspective and this try except would make sense! :)

Comment: That is not true, `print` works fine with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: only if encoding is parsed! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.format` instead of `%` to format strings. I also reworded the prompt slightly.

```
def calculator(number1,number2):
    print("Number1 is {} and number2 is {}\n".format(number1,number2) +
          "The sum is {}".format(number1+number2))
    if input("Is this correct (yes or no): ").strip().lower().startswith("y"):
        print("Knew it!")
    else:
        print("Oh, well. Blame my programmer!")
calculator(5,5)
```

Comment: `str.format` is superior to '%' formatting in almost all ways ([StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format#5082482)). Also, the way OP handles `input` and `print` are common to all versions of Python 3, not just 3.6.

Comment: @Coal_ may I ask why str.format() is superior to '%' formatting? I haven't coded long enough to learn why myself.

Comment: `str.format` automatically finds good string representations for most types without the hassle of using tuples. I suggest you read [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), especially [the rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#rationale) will be of interest to you.